# Can't build APK using Qt Creator due to gradle error

Tags: android, gradle, qt-creator

I am trying to build a project for Android on MacOS with Qt Creator 4.14, Qt 5.15.2, NDK 3.0, SDK 21.3.6528147.  Qt shows green checkmarks for Java/Android/OpenSSL

When I compile my app I see these errors during the "Generating Android Package" step (I think that's gradle called by qtdeployandroid):

```
Initialized native services in: /Users/admin/.gradle/native
The client will now receive all logging from the daemon (pid: 1778). The daemon log file: /Users/admin/.gradle/daemon/5.6.4/daemon-1778.out.log
Starting 9th build in daemon [uptime: 53 mins 14.777 secs, performance: 99%]
Using 2 worker leases.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not create service of type ScriptPluginFactory using BuildScopeServices.createScriptPluginFactory().
> Could not create service of type FileHasher using BuildSessionScopeServices.createFileSnapshotter().

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 971ms
Building the android package failed!
20:04:18: The process "/Users/admin/Qt/5.15.2/android/bin/androiddeployqt" exited with code 14.
Error while building/deploying project BFChristmasParty (kit: Android Qt 5.15.2 Clang Multi-Abi)
When executing step "Build Android APK"
20:04:18: Elapsed time: 01:42.
```

My project resides on a SMB share in case that matters.

Answer (score 0):

Check permissions of `/Users/admin/.gradle/native`... and you can navigate to the directory and then run `./gradlew assembleDebug  --stacktrace` (it may also be `gradle` or `assemble`, depending how it is set up).

Comment: permissions are ok.  But - I am running on a SMB share in case that matters.  I have added to question

Comment: Likely you'd need to use the local file-system, because SMB lacks a few features it provides; eg. SMB cannot exclusively lock files - and it may fail while trying to perform this or a similar operation. SVN would rather be a suitable server-side - while checking out to the local file-system.

Comment: Another option would be to install Jenkins along with SMB... and then build on the remote host; so that it nevertheless would be local file-system access, instead of a network share.

Comment: Since I'm new to Andrpid this sounds like a hurdle I don't need right now...but that may work

Comment: Even a local Git repository would make life easier; as this more or less provides unlimited undo. Some kind of version control is kind of a must-have ...while CI/CD are nice to have (eg. to automatically build & test upon each commit).